# Wrong contineous rotation to car

Tags: unity, rigidbody

In my 2d game, I want to rotate car face based on collision detected. But at present after 3 to 4 collision its doing continuous rotation only rather than moving straight after collision.

Here is my straight movement related code:

```
myRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + transform.up * Time.deltaTime * GameManager.Instance.VehicleFreeMovingSpeed);
```

For better collision purpose, I have used Rigidbody position change approach.

Here is my collision time code:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other)
{
 if (other.gameObject.CompareTag (GameConstants.TAG_BOUNDARY)) {
     ContactPoint2D contact;
     contact = other.contacts [0];
     Vector3 reflectedVelocity = Vector3.Reflect (transform.up, contact.normal);
     direction = reflectedVelocity;
 } 
}

if (direction != Vector3.zero && pathGenerator.positionList.Count <= 0) {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle - 90f, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRot, 0.1f);

        if (Quaternion.Angle (transform.rotation, targetRot) < 5f) {
            transform.rotation = targetRot;
            direction = Vector3.zero;
        }

    }
```

Rotation get applied within other code so that car was changing its face correctly and that method not affecting here that I have checked by placing debug statement.

Share you side thought for this.

Comment: I understand you don't think the rotation code is relevant here, but it would still help if we can see it to verify whether there are any unexpected interactions. From the code you've shown, we can't see how you use the `direction` variable to inform the car's rotation, so it's hard to guess where it's going wrong.

Comment: Okay sir let me put that code too....